# Spring application profile name suggestion

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What is the standard naming convention to create several peer profile.

`application-peer1-test.properties` or `application-peer1_test.properties`

Comment: by convention it is preferred to use either `-` throughout or `_`. So either `application-peer1-test.properties` or `application_peer1_test.properties`. I personally prefer the former.

Answer (score 5):

Naming of the profiles is up to you.

I think that best practice in this case would be not to mix different approaches and best name would be `application-peer1-test.properties`